# What is the reason for getting 3688 error in nonC03 in IBM content management

Tags: content-management-system

What is the reason for getting **3688** error in nonC03 in **IBM content management**

The full message is:

> 3688; 284; RETRIEVE; CM;0.258;0.214;00004; ;5135CB42B3A30B70E10080000AAFC46C;ZBVTBV-0000000000000016381‌​6302EN.doc;;/home/ic‌​csap/instances/R92/t‌​emp/cs_HTTP512102909‌​1740484441.tmp; 3688; 285; RETRIEVE; CM;0.176;0.019;00001; ;5135CB42B3A30B70E10080000AAFC46C;ZBVTBV-0000000000000016381‌​6302EN.doc;;/home/ic‌​csap/instances/R92/t‌​emp/cs_HTTP625757012‌​6991930845.tmp;

Comment: can you post the entire error message?

Comment: 3688;  284;     RETRIEVE;        CM;0.258;0.214;00004;               ;5135CB42B3A30B70E10080000AAFC46C;ZBVTBV-00000000000000163816302EN.doc;;/home/iccsap/instances/R92/temp/cs_HTTP5121029091740484441.tmp;
3688;  285;     RETRIEVE;        CM;0.176;0.019;00001;               ;5135CB42B3A30B70E10080000AAFC46C;ZBVTBV-00000000000000163816302EN.doc;;/home/iccsap/instances/R92/temp/cs_HTTP6257570126991930845.tmp;